# running this gives me null pointer exp. but runs fine when i remove comment '//' infrontof a[0]=b;

Tags: java, abstract

```
abstract class A{
    void show(){System.out.println("asasas");}    
}
class B extends A{}
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){
        A[] a=new A[5];
        B b=new B();
        //a[0]=b;
        a[0].show(); 
     }
}
```

> can abstract class object be instantiated??
>   can array of objects of abstract class be instantiated
>   running this gives me null pointer exp. but runs fine when i remove comment '//' infrontof a[0]=b;

Comment: Worth flagging this as Java, since other languages also have abstract classes.

Answer (score 1):

Well you aren't putting anything in the array a, so a is initialized with null at all indices.

You can have an array of an abstract class, but it's entries will all have to be instances of non-abstract classes that extend the abstract class

Answer (score 0):

All you've done is created the array, but all of its values are `null`: `a[0]` is null.  Your commented out line gives it a value so calling the method won't result in an NPE.

As for the abstract class business - you can't instantiate it directly, but can instantiate an anonymous instance of `A` like this:

```
A a = new A() {
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("hello from A");
    }
};
```